# Can't resolve 'video-react' in '/path/to/myapp/src'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am importing a local module in React like this:

`import { Player } from 'video-react';`

I have downloaded the module locally from https://github.com/video-react/video-react. (I intend to make some changes to it to customize it).

The module resides in `/path/to/video-react` - so it is a sister path to `myapp`. My `package.json` file has this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "video-react": "file:../video-react",
  },
```

I have deleted my `package-lock.json` file and run `npm install --save ../video-react`. When I run `npm start` I get a message:

`Module not found: Can't resolve 'video-react' in '/path/to/myapp/src'`. I have confirmed it is in my `node_modules` folder.

Comment: Why clone the repo and not just use `npm i --save video-react`?

Comment: Like I said I'd like to make changes to it.